# How to edit the file in swiftyDropbox?

Tags: ios, dropbox, swiftydropbox

In my project, I uploaded all my text files to the Dropbox. Here, I need to directly edit the uploaded file in Dropbox using **swift**. Is it possible to edit files in **Dropbox**?
(OR) Is it possible to overwrite the same fileName in Dropbox?

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/API-support/How-to-edit-the-file-in-the-Dropbox-using-swift/m-p/222294 (fixed link) ]

Comment: @Greg  How should I fetch the profile picture of the user account to my program.

Comment: [Cross-linking for reference: https://www.dropboxforum.com/t5/API-support/How-to-edit-the-file-in-the-Dropbox-using-swift/m-p/222498 ]

Answer (score 0):

[Solution moved](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/309552/997587) from [@SathishKumarGurunathan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/7756686/sathish-kumar-gurunathan)'s question post.

> I found the answer and I will share here.
>
> ```
>  _ = client?.files.upload(path: path, mode: .overwrite, autorename: false, clientModified: nil, mute: false, input: Description).response { response, error in
>
>     if let response = response {
>         
>         print("The upload response is \(response)")
>         
>     } else if let error = error {
>         
>         print("The upload error is \(error)")
>     }
>     }
>     .progress { progressData in
>         
>         print("The progress Data is \(progressData)")
> }
> ```